# How to calculate birth year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In TSQL, how can the year of birth be calculated?

I have tried datediff options but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: What exactly have you tried yet? What is the exact input and expected output?

Comment: How exactly do you want to calculate the birth year? What parameters or values do you have to work with?

Comment: If all you've got is an age, then there's no way to know for sure unless you know whether the birthday has already happened this year yet. In general, storing age is a bad idea because it changes. If you're instead storing the date of birth (the sensible thing to do), what even is your question?

Comment: The expected output would be the year of birth, 1966 for example. The calculation would be current year - age, or something to that effect?

Comment: Thanks Dannyg9090, you got me off on a good start. It was what i was after.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have age, you have already lost information. you can never know for sure the year of birth. This will approximate the YOB

```
dateadd(yy,-Age,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

You could slightly improve the accuracy of this guess by trying to adjust for the probability of whether the individual has had a birthday this year.

```
dateadd(yy,case when month(current_timestamp) <= 6 then 0 else 1 end-Age,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

You will want to substitute CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for the time that the age metric was acquired if you are retro-applying this to an existing dataset (assuming that data is available).

Above all, I would recommend changing your process to capture date of birth upfront if possible.